# Cross compile mono for arm

Tags: mono, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

Has anyone successfully cross-compiled mono for ARM under Linux without scratchbox or qemu?

(maybe with distcc or some cross-compiler toolchain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to cross compile mono(2.0, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 2.10.1) with Scratchbox 2 installed on a Ubuntu machine using CodeSourcery Lite tool chain. I used the article from the [Mono project page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aARM).

First compile it on the native machine

```
./configure
$ make
$ make install DESTDIR=path
```

Then in sb2:

```
[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > ./configure --disable-mcs-build
[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > make 
[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > make install DESTDIR=path
```

I use this for configuration

```
./configure --enable-minimal=profiler,debug,logging,soft_debug --with-tls=--with-tls=__thread --with-monotouch=no --without-mcs-docs --disable-mono-debugger CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_NONE --disable-mcs-build
```

Comment: hmm i tried the ./configure --disable-mcs-build, but i failed with lots of undefined references, i will tomorrow test your configuration

Comment: which toolchain do you use in the sbox environment? is your DESTDIR the same in both environments or do you merge later after building?

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer. yes the destdir is the same.(Note: I changed the toolchain, using crosstool-ng)

Comment: Disabling MCS doesn't work for me either. It seems to fail on the test program steps.

Comment: When you compile mono on the native machine you should not use --disable-mcs-build. After install run clean and rerun configure with the disable mcs in sb2

Comment: do any of you gents have any help, man pages, tutorials, with a step-by-step process of how to do all of this?  I'm presently looking at doing the same, but everything i see here is a set of notes from someone with experience, not suited for a n00b doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried and tried and tried with scratchbox2 last night.. Ran into some problem.. Ended up just compiling on arm, went fine! took 30 minutes!

```
CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_VFP_HARD HardFloat
CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_VFP_NONE SoftFloat
```

Compile mono on PC

```
sudo make install `directory like /tmptree etc`
```

move all these files from /tmptree over to / etc on your arm device.

```
./autogen.sh --disable-mcs-build
make CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_VFP_HARD
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

[Mono Hard Float Patch](https://github.com/directhex/mono-1/commit/3a28afb60e21428dc6a773aaed5153f0dbef4f28)

Tried doing Hard Float with mono 3.0.3.. it said it didn't support it yet.